# How to make JMETER send a form post to a path with a QUERYSTRING?

Tags: windows, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm using JMeter for some performance testing.  I've recorded my test case using the proxy, and am running into a snag trying to replay it.

Basically, I have a HTTP post and its posting to a page that contains a QUERYSTRING.

> **Sampler Path:**  http://dev.mysite.com/myform.aspx?formfunction=SEARCH
>
> **POST DATA:** searchitem=dogs

Issue that I'm running into is that myform.aspx will be passed the post data, but its not returning the expected response.  **Its returning a response as if the querystring (?formfunction=SEARCH) wasn't even included.**  Without the querystring, it runs a default SEARCH, but if the querystring is included, it runs a different search with the searchitem included in the post data.

How can I make JMeter recognize the querystring I'm sending in my sampler path??

Comment: Is it valid in http to have a get and post parameter at the same time?

Comment: I believe so -- I don't necessarily see why you need to POST data to a page and then have that page process a post in order to figure out what content to display.  I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it -- but its not far fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try taking the parameter out of the path, and add it as a post data item below.

So, in your HTTP request - under "parameters" you should see  "searchitem:dogs".  click "Add" to create a new parameter, with the name "formfunction" and value "SEARCH"